# LOVE2D can't find the font file?

Tags: fonts, lua, syntax-error, love2d

I have my main.lua within the same directory as the .ttf font file and yet, it still gives me an error message saying the file can't be found?
I'm running version 0.10.2

This code is within love.load function

```
mainFont = love.graphics.newFont('font.ttf', 9)

love.graphics.setFont(mainFont)
```

Image of Error Message

[image: Image of Error Message]

Image of Font File

[image: Image of Font File]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I had to run the main.lua through the CMD rather than changing the extension to zip then to love.